# How to Get SqlServerSpatial to work on Azure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I am trying to upload my asp.net web api till an azure website. I am running problems with Spatial stuff in EF.

I first got an error when trying to insert data into my database via EF but was able to fix it by using "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types".

Now it seems when I try to get data out of the database I get an error

> Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial.dll': The specified module could
>   not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I tried to install SqlServerSpatial110.dll as I saw some articles talk about this(but they where from Aug 2011) but it comes back with some Com error back.

How do I get Spatial to work?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba8fb83c-3f77-4a43-a898-923dde5762b5/microsoftsqlservertypes-sqlserverspatialdll-issues-on-azure?forum=ssdsgetstarted) from 2012; this is working for me. It's a matter of getting the right DLL in the correct location in your project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlServerSpatial.dll` comes with SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack. The latest version is available here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30440

Depending on the version of the SQL Server, you need to download and install these

```
SQLSysClrTypes_amd64.msi
SQLSysClrTypes_ia64.msi
SQLSysClrTypes_x86.msi
```

They contain sqlserverspatial.dll and C runtimes which is installed in `SysWOW64`, and `System32`